# Highcharts tooltip visibility issue with large dataset

Tags: javascript, jquery, highcharts

I have large dataset, which creates Highchart with 100 categories and requires overflow to be auto, to easily scroll down. But, the tooltip always appear on right-top side of cursor, it doesn't adjust the position automatically according to the overflow. 
I am using following tooltip configuration.

```
tooltip: {
                followPointer: true,
                useHTML: true,
                 formatter: function() {
                     var strresp = "the test line 1</br>line 2 </br> line 3 </br>line 4</br> line 5</br> line 6 </br> line 7";
                   return strresp;
                 }
            },
```

Please check the [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/nftn6/1/) for example. 
If we scroll down and hover on the 6/7 category in fiddle, the tooltip will get cutoff from top. Is there any possible way to fix it using tooltip positioner?
Please suggest some solution.

Thanks

Comment: Each use case is different...but why on earth constrain your chart into that little container?

Comment: You could use `<span>the test line 1</span><span>line 2</span>` and set the style on those to `span { display: block; }`, which would decrease the vertical spacing between the lines of text, however as pointed out above, this amount of space is quite restrictive and not very flexible!

Comment: As I have mentioned above, I have large data sets with 100 categories in chart, and I want to provide scroll option to users for an easy interface that is the reason to constrain the chart inside a container with specific height.

Comment: See the similiar topic http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18658043/highcharts-pie-tooltip-cuts-off

Comment: Thanks @SebastianBochan for your suggestion, I added the suggested css in my fiddle http://jsfiddle.net/nftn6/2/ , but it won't help. Also, I want to change the position of tooltip, if it gets cutoff after scroll then ideally tooltip should appear on right-bottom of cursor.

Comment: You can modify positin by tooltip positioner: http://api.highcharts.com/highcharts#tooltip.positioner

Comment: I know that positioner is available to change the position, but I am not sure how to change the alignment of tooltips and how to detect the   tooltip gets cutoff.